# Make google chart work with large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

**What I have done**
I have added google charts to my page. The data is populated based on the date and duration the user selects. (The duration can be any amount of hours).

**What I need to do**
I need to ensure that the chart can accommodate the duration selected. By spacing the gant data and making the chart movable.

**The problem**

Is that I cannot get the chart to accomodate large sets of data without cramping the data. I need the data spaced out and thus make the chart movable (responsive) based on the amount of data searched for.

**The Code**

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = [];
  var header = ['Activity', 'Start Time', 'End Time'];
  data.push(header);

  for(var i =0; i < $scope.timelineArr.length;i++){
    var year = $scope.timelineArr[i].thumbnail_date.substring(0,4);
    var month = $scope.timelineArr[i].thumbnail_date.substring(5,7) -1;
    var day = $scope.timelineArr[i].thumbnail_date.substring(8,10);
    var hour = $scope.timelineArr[i].thumbnail_time.substring(0,2);
    var min = $scope.timelineArr[i].thumbnail_time.substring(3, 5);
    console.log(year+ " "+month+ " "+day);
    var tmp = [];
    tmp.push(""+$scope.timelineArr[i].cam_name, new Date(year, month, day, hour, min), new Date(year, month, day, hour, min));
    data.push(tmp);
  }

  $scope.data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
  var options = {
    'legend':'left',
    'title':'Camera Events',
    'is3D':true,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    },
    'width':1000,
    'height':400
  }

  $scope.chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  $scope.chart.draw($scope.data, options);
```

//////////

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

I also included what it looks like now.As you can see the data is cramped, imagine if I choose more hours. Thank you.[image: The results I get thus far]

Is there a way to make the timeline ZOOMABLE?

Comment: I decided to wrap the chart inside a div and increase the width depending on the amount of data. I then made the div scroll able, added an mouse-rollover listener to increase/decrease the div accordingly. Hope it helps someone.